# How do I take information from a file and use it to make a boolean true or false?

Tags: java

Hi I'm taking online Java classes and these are the instructions given to me:

1. For a family of two, calculate the percentage occurrence of the 
   three combinations: two boys, two girls, or one boy and one girl.
2. Your program should print the sample size, the percent of all boys, 
   all girls, and one boy and one girl.

The problem I'm running into is I can't figure out how to count the values of how many of each family there are for example if the sample size is 5 families where G is one Girl and B is one Boy and this is the example group
BG
GB
BB
GG
GB
How do I get it to print out that there were three families with a boy and a girl one family with two girls and one family with two boys? Here is the code that I have so Far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class family
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    String token = "";
    File fileName = new File("test1.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
    String BG =("BG");
    String GB =("GB");
    String BB =("BB");
    String GG =("GG");
    int sampleSize = 0;
    int twoBoys = 0;
    int oneBoyOneGirl = 0;
    int twoGirls = 0;
    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
        token = inFile.next( );
        System.out.println(token);
    }
    inFile.close();
    if(token == BG)
    {
        oneBoyOneGirl++;
    }
    else if(token == GB)
    {
        oneBoyOneGirl++;
    }
    else if(token == BB)
    {
        twoBoys++;
    }
    else
    {
        twoGirls++;
    }
    System.out.println("Sample Size: "+ sampleSize);
    System.out.println("Two Boys: "+ twoBoys);
    System.out.println("One Boy One Girl: "+ oneBoyOneGirl);
    System.out.println("Two Girls: "+ twoGirls);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is only looking at the last token.  The if-else block should be executed within the loop after retrieving each token, and then print out the values outside the loop.

Furthermore, you should not use token == BB, as that will not work correctly. Try token.equals(BB) instead.